# Can bus / OBDII reader to export data via API

Tags: scanner, api

I need to buy a can bus scanner, through OBD2 port, that provide API service for extract raw data (like AutoPi TMU: https://www.autopi.io/hardware-dongle/generation-three/). Do you know anything like that?

My main goal is to extract data from can bus and analyze it automatically; therefore, I would need API (or something similar) to be able to pull the data, detected by a can bus scanner, for me on a regular basis (e.g., every day).

Do you have any products to recommend?

Comment: Raw CAN data or "raw" ODB2 data?
For the former, a Teensy board has CAN support you could then relay via serial (USB), SPI, I2C etc.

Comment: @towe I need to extract these data remotely (via API)

Comment: Remotely as in wireless? The scanner remains plugged in and you just connect to it via phone / laptop etc.?

Comment: @towe I supposed that system send data in cloud (or something like that) and, then, I can extract these data via API.